# Get Progress of PHP Script using jQuery.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress

I am using jQuery's ajax to run a php script with the below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my_php_script.php",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error is...');
    }
});
```

`my_php_script.php` loops through an array and on each product runs a function:

```
$count = count($array);
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    myFunction($item);
    $i++;
    if($i == $count){
        echo json_encode('all done and a success');
    }
}
```

This all works but the script can generally take around 2-3 minutes to finish so I need to show the progress for the viewer whilst it runs. How can i do this?

I can get the percent of the loop by adding

```
$percent = intval($i/$count * 100)."%";
echo json_encode($percent);
```

into my php loop as so:

```
$count = count($array);
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    myFunction($item);

    $percent = intval($i/$count * 100)."%";
    echo json_encode($percent);

    $i++;
    if($i == $count){
        echo json_encode('all done and a success');
    }
}
```

But how can i get this value in my jQuery ajax call?

Comment: you are doing "echo" into the loop. Doesn't it return output to ajax call?

Comment: At the moment it does but only on success as that's the only time i currently get the response back, I was thinking I need to be able to have a `progress` callback on the ajax call to show this?

Comment: You need to use "beforeSend" parameter of ajax calling. See this: 
http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/

Comment: I think beforeSend is now outdatted isn't it? I've tried both examples in the link and it still doesn't show/work

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    xhrFields: {
        onprogress: function (e) {

        }
    },
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```

Found this example hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @wayzz but on trying that code i still can't get the actual progress. The 'loading' state shows before success but not the progress percent - i edited and updated so it should log the precent on progress but i't doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/r86gM/68/

Answer (score 0):

Got this working in the end by writing the percentage in a uniquely named text file as so in my array loop:

```
$percent = intval($i/$count * 100)."%";
$_text = file_get_contents($_file);
$_text = $percent;
file_put_contents($_file, $_text);
```

And then in my html page i check the contents of the file every 2 seconds by:

```
jQuery.get('file.txt?'+new Date(), function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, 'text');
```

I'm sure this isn't the best way of doing so but to get this working in a limited time period it's all i could come up with. Hope it helps anyone else